# Validate UTC date/date-time with ajv but allow empty strings

Tags: javascript, ajv

I need to validate string schema format: `"date"` or format: `"date-time"` to accept only **ISO 8601** but also allow empty string "" (the "" requirement should be separately checked using the required schema).

```
{
   "datetime1": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
   }
}
```

However, the native ajv format parser does not allow empty string "" to pass. How do I make it allow empty string, and still validate ISO 8601?

Do I really have to write my own format checker using `ajv.addFormat()`? I also have the same issue for `"format": "email"`, where I also need "" to be valid.

**Note:** I can't modify the schema, so I can't add defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets try to use oneOf

```
date_to: {
  type: 'string',
  oneOf: [
    {
      maxLength: 0
    },
    {
      format: 'date-time',
      minLength: 1
    }
  ]
},
```

in the first object, it will allows empty string. In the second object, it will check input based on your format